# Push To Angular JS Array

Tags: angularjs, push

I'm running into a strange issue when executing the .push() method on an angular js collection. In the console I can see the object is added, but I cannot actually see it added to the list.

```
    $scope.discountCodes.push({
                discountCodeId: 0,
                name: $scope.discountModel.name,
                code: $scope.discountModel.code,
                codeValue: $scope.discountModel.codeValue,
                valueType: $scope.discountModel.valueType,
                startDate: $scope.discountModel.startDate,
                endDate: $scope.discountModel.endDate,
                isActive: "True"
            });
```

I have a simple repeater combined with a template

```
    <div ng-repeat="discount in discountCodes" ng-include="getTemplate(discount)">
                                </div>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="display">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <span>Name:<br />{{discount.Name}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <span>Code:<br />{{discount.Code}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <span>Value:<br />{{discount.CodeValue}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <span>Active:<br /></span>
                            <i class="icon-circle green-fill"
                               ng-show="discount.IsActive">
                            </i>
                            <i class="icon-circle red-fill"
                               ng-show="!discount.IsActive">
                            </i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2"><br />
                            <a href="#" ng-click="editDiscount(discount)" id="lnkEditRow" name="lnkEditRow" class="gray-fill"><i class="icon-edit icon-2x"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </script>
```

This is the method:
                $scope.discountModel.formSubmit = function (item, event) {

```
        $scope.alertMessageContainerVisible = false;

        if ($scope.frmDiscountForm.$valid) {
            var dataObject = {
                discountCodeId: 0,
                name: $scope.discountModel.name,
                code: $scope.discountModel.code,
                codeValue: $scope.discountModel.codeValue,
                valueType: $scope.discountModel.valueType,
                startDate: $scope.discountModel.startDate,
                endDate: $scope.discountModel.endDate,
                isActive: "True"
            };
            action = "NEW";

            $scope.discountCodes.push(dataObject)
            });
        }
    }
```

Any ideas are helpful, I am new to Angular JS so be easy on me :)

I created a very simple version of this below:
http://plnkr.co/edit/qJDU7uiFleWIOjR5LYFh

Comment: I think JSON is case sensitive. Try `discount.name` instead of `discount.Name` in your template.

Comment: show where you call this push from. If it's an event outside of angular world you need to notify angular to run a digest

Comment: As @Pete said, JSON is case sensitive, you are calling every JSON property inside the template with capital letter as discount.Name. eg

Comment: I made sure the case matched in both the object I'm pushing to the collection and also in the template. Still cannot get the new object to show up even though it gets added to the collection

Comment: I created this simple version, still no luck:
http://plnkr.co/edit/qJDU7uiFleWIOjR5LYFh

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might be updating the collection outside of the Angular context.  If so, you'll need to use $scope.$apply() for Angular to see your changes.

Comment: I'm noticing a few things in the first Plunker you posted.  You've got multiple references to the same ng-controller on the same view.  You should only reference the controller one time.  Also, make sure you're using the same casing between the model in your view and the controller.  For example, in your form you're using ng-model="discountModel.name" where name is camel cased.  In your model on the controller and in the template you're using Pascal casing 'Name'.   Here's a Plunker that shows the example working with a few modifications.  http://plnkr.co/edit/FyJf1WKtdaheAgDtJIF5?p=preview

Comment: I've reviewed your second Plunker and made a few modifications to get it working.  The same general items from my previous post apply.  Make sure to only include one ng-controller reference and make sure you're using the same casing between your model and view.  You might also consider using ng-submit to submit the form data to your controller.  Here's the modified Plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/YNIEb7z8cEZfILTKszHq?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for all that! Everything is working great now!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a stupid mistake! I had my controller defined in the body and in the div, so it was in two places. Now everything is working good!

Thanks all, it was  good learning experience